# Transferring data from VM Instances to BigQuery in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to transfer some files to BigQuery which are stored in my VM Instances. Normally we do a two steps process:

1. Transfer files from VM instances to Cloud Storage bucket.
2. Getting data from Cloud Storage bucket to BigQuery.

Now, I want to take files directly from VM Instances to BigQuery platform. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load data directly from a readable data source (such as your local machine) by using:

- The Cloud Console or the classic BigQuery web UI
- The bq command-line tool's bq load command
- The API
- The client libraries

Please, follow the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source) to see examples of using each way.

Moreover, if you want to stay with idea of sending your files to Cloud Storage bucket, you can think about using Dataflow templates:

- Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery ([Stream](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#gcstexttobigquerystream))
- Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery ([Batch](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcstexttobigquery))

which allows you to read text files stored in Cloud Storage, transform them using a JavaScript User Defined Function (UDF) that you provide, and output the result to BigQuery. It is automated solution.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: The command looks like this: 
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV x.y  abc.csv

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use bq command for this.
The command would be like this:
**bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV x.y abc.csv**